# Find the dimensionality of a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the most efficient and/or most readable way to write a function that takes in an array and returns the degree of multi-dimensionality of that array. For now it can be assumed that the arrays only contain primitive types.

Example.

```
    var arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

    function findDim(a){
    //logic goes here
    }

    findDim(arr); // returns 2
```

Comment: What would be  "dimensionality" of this one: `[ 1, [2,3], [[4]] ]`?

Comment: we can say this function should calculate the max dimenstionality - so 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use recursion and **[`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)** method to check element is an array.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];

function findD(arr) {
  // check the element is an array then do 
  // recursion to check it's element
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return 1 + findD(arr[0]);
  }
  // else return `0` since it's not
  // a nested array
  return 0;
}

console.log(findD(arr));
```

---

**FYI :** For older browser check [polyfill option of `Array.isArray` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Polyfill).

---

**UPDATE :** Incase it contains different  dimensioned array and you want to get the deeper dimension then use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)** methods.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, [6]]
];

function findD(arr) {
  // return 0 if not array else return the max value 
  // by finding all elements dimension
  return Array.isArray(arr) ?
    // generate the dimension value array 
    1 + Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(findD)) : 0;
}

console.log(findD(arr));
```

---

Or with **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method to get the max value.

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, [4,[[3]]]],
  [5, [6]]
];

function findD(arr) {
  // return 0 if not array else return the max value 
  // by finding all elements dimension
  return Array.isArray(arr) ? 1 + arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    // get the largest by comparing all the adjuscent 
    // elements dimension
    return Math.max(a, findD(b));
  }, 0) : 0;
}

console.log(findD(arr));
```

Comment: Now it' is much better

Comment: `function(v) { return findD(v) }` doesn't make much sense though.

Answer (score 2):

"Dimensionality" is not well defined for js arrays (which are not necessary matrices), here's a function to find the max "depth" of the array:

```js
maxDepth = x => Array.isArray(x)
  ? 1 + Math.max.apply(this, x.map(maxDepth))
  : 0
;

console.log(maxDepth([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]))
console.log(maxDepth([[[[1]]], 2]))
```

Comment: This is the only one answer that works (well.. along with mine -:)  )

Comment: @Redu: well, the OP didn't say how they (or their teacher) want to handle irregular arrays... not exactly sure what is more "correct" here.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do. It's valid for irregularly multidimensional arrays;

```js
var arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,[6,[7,[8]]]]],
findDim = a => Math.max(...a.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? findDim(e) : 0)) + 1
console.log(findDim(arr))
```