# find country coordinates from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am writing a small app. I have following data

```
{
  "feat": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "id": "AFG",
          "properties": {
            "name": "Afghanistan"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [ 
              [
                [
                  61.210817,
                  35.650072
                ],
                [
                  64.546479,
                  36.312073
                ],
                [
                  64.746105,
                  37.111818
                ],
                [
                  65.588948,
                  37.305217
                ],
                [
                  65.745631,
                  37.661164
                ],
                [
                  66.217385,
                  37.39379
                ],
                [
                  66.518607,
                  37.362784
                ],
                [
                  67.075782,
                  37.356144
                ],
                [
                  67.83,
                  37.144994
                ],
                [
                  68.135562,
                  37.023115
                ],
                [
                  68.859446,
                  37.344336
                ],
                [
                  69.196273,
                  37.151144
                ],
                [
                  69.518785,
                  37.608997
                ],
                [
                  70.116578,
                  37.588223
                ],
                [
                  70.270574,
                  37.735165
                ],
                [
                  71.262348,
                  36.074388
                ],
                [
                  71.498768,
                  35.650563
                ],
                [
                  71.613076,
                  35.153203
                ],
                [
                  71.115019,
                  34.733126
                ],
                [
                  71.156773,
                  34.348911
                ],
                [
                  70.881803,
                  33.988856
                ],
                [
                  69.930543,
                  34.02012
                ],
                [
                  70.323594,
                  33.358533
                ],
                [
                  69.687147,
                  33.105499
                ],
                [
                  69.262522,
                  32.501944
                ],
                [
                  69.317764,
                  31.901412
                ],
                [
                  68.926677,
                  31.620189
                ],
                [
                  68.556932,
                  31.71331
                ],
                [
                  67.792689,
                  31.58293
                ],
                [
                  60.52843,
                  33.676446
                ],
                [
                  60.803193,
                  34.404102
                ],
                [
                  61.210817,
                  35.650072
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "id": "AGO",
          "properties": {
            "name": "Angola"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  [
                    16.326528,
                    -5.87747
                  ],
                  [
                    16.57318,
                    -6.622645
                  ],
                  [
                    16.860191,
                    -7.222298
                  ],
                  [
                    17.089996,
                    -7.545689
                  ],
                  [
                    17.47297,
                    -8.068551
                  ],
                  [
                    21.801801,
                    -8.908707
                  ],
                  [
                    21.875182,
                    -9.523708
                  ],
                  [
                    22.208753,
                    -9.894796
                  ],
                  [
                    22.155268,
                    -11.084801
                  ],
                  [
                    22.402798,
                    -10.993075
                  ],
                  [
                    22.837345,
                    -11.017622
                  ],
                  [
                    23.456791,
                    -10.867863
                  ],
                  [
                    23.912215,
                    -10.926826
                  ],
                  [
                    24.017894,
                    -11.237298
                  ],
                  [
                    23.904154,
                    -11.722282
                  ],
                  [
                    24.079905,
                    -12.191297
                  ],
                  [
                    23.930922,
                    -12.565848
                  ],
                  [
                    24.016137,
                    -12.911046
                  ],
                  [
                    21.933886,
                    -12.898437
                  ],
                  [
                    21.887843,
                    -16.08031
                  ],
                  [
                    22.562478,
                    -16.898451
                  ],
                  [
                    23.215048,
                    -17.523116
                  ],
                  [
                    21.377176,
                    -17.930636
                  ],
                  [
                    18.956187,
                    -17.789095
                  ],
                  [
                    18.263309,
                    -17.309951
                  ],
                  [
                    12.175619,
                    -14.449144
                  ],
                  [
                    12.500095,
                    -13.5477
                  ],
                  [
                    12.738479,
                    -13.137906
                  ],
                  [
                    13.312914,
                    -12.48363
                  ],
                  [
                    13.633721,
                    -12.038645
                  ],
                  [
                    13.738728,
                    -11.297863
                  ],
                  [
                    13.686379,
                    -10.731076
                  ],
                  [
                    13.387328,
                    -10.373578
                  ],
                  [
                    13.120988,
                    -9.766897
                  ],
                  [
                    12.87537,
                    -9.166934
                  ],
                  [
                    13.375597,
                    -5.864241
                  ],
                  [
                    16.326528,
                    -5.87747
                  ]
                ]
              ],
              [
                [
                  [
                    12.436688,
                    -5.684304
                  ],
                  [
                    12.182337,
                    -5.789931
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "id": "ALB",
          "properties": {
            "name": "Albania"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  20.590247,
                  41.855404
                ],
                [
                  19.406082,
                  40.250773
                ],
                [
                  19.319059,
                  40.72723
                ],
                [
                  19.40355,
                  41.409566
                ],
                [
                  19.540027,
                  41.719986
                ],
                [
                  19.371769,
                  41.877548
                ],
                [
                  19.304486,
                  42.195745
                ],
                [
                  19.738051,
                  42.688247
                ],
                [
                  19.801613,
                  42.500093
                ],
                [
                  20.0707,
                  42.58863
                ],
                [
                  20.283755,
                  42.32026
                ],
                [
                  20.52295,
                  42.21787
                ],
                [
                  20.590247,
                  41.855404
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
    ]
}
```

What happens is that user will provide `latitude` and `longitude`. Then I need to find if those values are present in above dataset. if it is then return that country.

The problem is that above dataset coordinates array is different. Sometimes it is 3 dimensional and sometimes it is 2.It is keep changing. I am not sure how can I find efficient solution for this.

Below is some of my code which currently it prompts user from latitude and longitude and and loop through data.

```
const rl = require('readline').createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
const coordinates = require('./data.json').feat;

var prompts = ['Enter coordinates (lat, lon)'],
    counter = 0;

// console.log(countries);

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    if (!line) {
        console.log('Enter values.');
    }

    let lat = line.split(' ')[0],
        lon = line.split(' ')[1];

    console.log(lat, lon);

    coordinates.forEach((data, index) => {
        console.log(data.geometry.coordinates[index]);
        data.geometry.coordinates.forEach((geo, i) => {
            // console.log(geo[i]);
        });
    });

    get();
}).on('close', () => {

});

function get() {
    rl.setPrompt(prompts[counter] + ': ');
    rl.prompt();
}

get();
```

**Any help in finding given longitude and latitude in above dataset?**

Comment: As evident from your sample data, it does provide information about the type of data set (`Poygon`, `multipolygon`), so how about preprocess your set of coordinates into a general set of coordinates (2D, or 3D, as it may suit you) and then run an iteration over that set?

Comment: If your only problem is the unpredictable dimension of the received `coordinates` array then i would suggest you to [find the dimension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39234419/4543207) of that array first and if it's bigger than 2 then do a dimension reduction like `coordinates = [].concat(coordinates)`

Comment: @SayedAhadAbbas how can we do that? Can you give any answer instead?

Comment: https://github.com/turfjs/turf/

Comment: @cartant I would need to do it in pure javascript. No external libraries or modules :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the number of polygons by checking the `type` property. If it is `MultiPolygon`, you'll have one more nested level.

Here are some functions you could use to determine whether a point is in a polygon. The rest (lower part) of the snippet allows to test the `getCountry` function: it performs the map drawing, mouse move handling and showing the country which the mouse moves over. But the essence is in the three functions at the top.

This is plain JS, based on the winding algorithm presented in [this article](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html) but you might want to consider using a library for that instead, like [d3.js](https://d3js.org/).

```js
function isLeft(p0, p1, p2) {
    return ( (p1[0] - p0[0]) * (p2[1] - p0[1])
           - (p2[0] - p0[0]) * (p1[1] - p0[1]) );
}

function inPoly(p, coord) {
    var winding = 0;
    // loop through all edges of the polygon
    for (var i=0; i<coord.length-1; i++) {
        if (coord[i][1] <= p[1]) {
            if (coord[i+1][1]  > p[1])     // an upward crossing
                 if (isLeft(coord[i], coord[i+1], p) > 0)  // p left of edge
                     ++winding;            // have  a valid up intersect
        } else {                           // start y > P.y (no test needed)
            if (coord[i+1][1] <= p[1])     // a downward crossing
                 if (isLeft(coord[i], coord[i+1], p) < 0)  // p right of  edge
                     --winding;            // have  a valid down intersect
        }
    }
    return winding;
}

function getCountry(p, data) {
    // p: point represented by array with the two coordinates
    var country;
    return data.feat.some(function (obj) {
        country = obj;
        var polygons = obj.geometry.coordinates;
        if (obj.geometry.type !== 'MultiPolygon') polygons = [polygons];
        return polygons.some(function (polygon) {
            return inPoly(p, polygon[0]);
        });
    }) ? country : null;
}

// I/O for this interactive snippet

function drawPolygon(ctx, coord, fillColor) {
    ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
    ctx.beginPath();
    coord.forEach(function (point, i) {
        if (i==0) {
            ctx.moveTo(point[0], point[1]);
        } else {
            ctx.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
        }
    });
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
//    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawCountry(ctx, selectedCountry, country) {
    var polygons = country.geometry.coordinates;
    var color = selectedCountry == country ? 'yellow' : 'grey';
    if (country.geometry.type !== 'MultiPolygon') polygons = [polygons];
    polygons.forEach(function (polygon) {
        drawPolygon(ctx, polygon[0], color);
    });
}

function drawWorld(ctx, data, selectedCountry) {
    data.feat.forEach(drawCountry.bind(null, ctx, selectedCountry));
}

// Define transformation so countries will be mapped to canvas area
var scale = [3, -3];
var move = [-20, 130];

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(...move);
ctx.scale(...scale);
ctx.lineWidth = 1/scale[0];

// Sample data
var data = {"feat":[{"type":"Feature","id":"AFG","properties":{"name":"Afghanistan"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.210817,35.650072],[62.230651,35.270664],[62.984662,35.404041],[63.193538,35.857166],[63.982896,36.007957],[64.546479,36.312073],[64.746105,37.111818],[65.588948,37.305217],[65.745631,37.661164],[66.217385,37.39379],[66.518607,37.362784],[67.075782,37.356144],[67.83,37.144994],[68.135562,37.023115],[68.859446,37.344336],[69.196273,37.151144],[69.518785,37.608997],[70.116578,37.588223],[70.270574,37.735165],[70.376304,38.138396],[70.806821,38.486282],[71.348131,38.258905],[71.239404,37.953265],[71.541918,37.905774],[71.448693,37.065645],[71.844638,36.738171],[72.193041,36.948288],[72.63689,37.047558],[73.260056,37.495257],[73.948696,37.421566],[74.980002,37.41999],[75.158028,37.133031],[74.575893,37.020841],[74.067552,36.836176],[72.920025,36.720007],[71.846292,36.509942],[71.262348,36.074388],[71.498768,35.650563],[71.613076,35.153203],[71.115019,34.733126],[71.156773,34.348911],[70.881803,33.988856],[69.930543,34.02012],[70.323594,33.358533],[69.687147,33.105499],[69.262522,32.501944],[69.317764,31.901412],[68.926677,31.620189],[68.556932,31.71331],[67.792689,31.58293],[67.683394,31.303154],[66.938891,31.304911],[66.381458,30.738899],[66.346473,29.887943],[65.046862,29.472181],[64.350419,29.560031],[64.148002,29.340819],[63.550261,29.468331],[62.549857,29.318572],[60.874248,29.829239],[61.781222,30.73585],[61.699314,31.379506],[60.941945,31.548075],[60.863655,32.18292],[60.536078,32.981269],[60.9637,33.528832],[60.52843,33.676446],[60.803193,34.404102],[61.210817,35.650072]]]}},{"type":"Feature","id":"AGO","properties":{"name":"Angola"},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[16.326528,-5.87747],[16.57318,-6.622645],[16.860191,-7.222298],[17.089996,-7.545689],[17.47297,-8.068551],[18.134222,-7.987678],[18.464176,-7.847014],[19.016752,-7.988246],[19.166613,-7.738184],[19.417502,-7.155429],[20.037723,-7.116361],[20.091622,-6.94309],[20.601823,-6.939318],[20.514748,-7.299606],[21.728111,-7.290872],[21.746456,-7.920085],[21.949131,-8.305901],[21.801801,-8.908707],[21.875182,-9.523708],[22.208753,-9.894796],[22.155268,-11.084801],[22.402798,-10.993075],[22.837345,-11.017622],[23.456791,-10.867863],[23.912215,-10.926826],[24.017894,-11.237298],[23.904154,-11.722282],[24.079905,-12.191297],[23.930922,-12.565848],[24.016137,-12.911046],[21.933886,-12.898437],[21.887843,-16.08031],[22.562478,-16.898451],[23.215048,-17.523116],[21.377176,-17.930636],[18.956187,-17.789095],[18.263309,-17.309951],[14.209707,-17.353101],[14.058501,-17.423381],[13.462362,-16.971212],[12.814081,-16.941343],[12.215461,-17.111668],[11.734199,-17.301889],[11.640096,-16.673142],[11.778537,-15.793816],[12.123581,-14.878316],[12.175619,-14.449144],[12.500095,-13.5477],[12.738479,-13.137906],[13.312914,-12.48363],[13.633721,-12.038645],[13.738728,-11.297863],[13.686379,-10.731076],[13.387328,-10.373578],[13.120988,-9.766897],[12.87537,-9.166934],[12.929061,-8.959091],[13.236433,-8.562629],[12.93304,-7.596539],[12.728298,-6.927122],[12.227347,-6.294448],[12.322432,-6.100092],[12.735171,-5.965682],[13.024869,-5.984389],[13.375597,-5.864241],[16.326528,-5.87747]]],[[[12.436688,-5.684304],[12.182337,-5.789931],[11.914963,-5.037987],[12.318608,-4.60623],[12.62076,-4.438023],[12.995517,-4.781103],[12.631612,-4.991271],[12.468004,-5.248362],[12.436688,-5.684304]]]]}},{"type":"Feature","id":"ALB","properties":{"name":"Albania"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[20.590247,41.855404],[20.463175,41.515089],[20.605182,41.086226],[21.02004,40.842727],[20.99999,40.580004],[20.674997,40.435],[20.615,40.110007],[20.150016,39.624998],[19.98,39.694993],[19.960002,39.915006],[19.406082,40.250773],[19.319059,40.72723],[19.40355,41.409566],[19.540027,41.719986],[19.371769,41.877548],[19.304486,42.195745],[19.738051,42.688247],[19.801613,42.500093],[20.0707,42.58863],[20.283755,42.32026],[20.52295,42.21787],[20.590247,41.855404]]]}}]};
// Show map on canvas
window.onload = drawWorld.bind(null, ctx, data, null);

// Handle mouse move to mention the matching country
canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
    // Get mouse coordinates relative to canvas
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    // Perform the reverse of the canvas transformation
    x = (x - move[0]) / scale[0];
    y = (y - move[1]) / scale[1];
    // Get country that contains this point
    var country = getCountry([x, y], data);
    var countryName = country ? country.properties.name : 'no match';
    // Output the result
    document.getElementById('country').textContent = countryName;
    // Highight country
    drawWorld(ctx, data, country)
};
```

```css
canvas { border:1px solid; float: left }
```

```html
<canvas width="250", height="200"></canvas>
<div id="country">Hover mouse...</div>
```

#### Note about performance

When you have a large list of polygons in your data set, it really is a waste of time to check each individual edge of each polygon to determine where the point fits.

It will be a major improvement if you would preprocess the data and add box information to each polygon: a square that encompasses the polygon completely (`[minx,miny]-[maxx,maxy]`). When you need to match a point, you would first match against this box, and if it is outside, you can skip that polygon, saving time spent on it. There will normally only be a few of those boxes that encompass your point, and so you would only need to test against those few polygons.

#### To just get the name of the country:

Call the `getCountry` function like it is done in the above snippet, where you pass the user defined `x` and `y` (i.e. longitude, latitude) as an array, and the `data` object as the second argument:

```
var country = getCountry([x, y], data);
var countryName = country ? country.properties.name : 'no match';
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution but I do not need to draw anything. inPoly function seems to be more complex because of the p parameter. It would be great to get a country with the lat long provided by user.

Comment: the thing is that it draws but I just want the name of the country. Currently inPoly function is complicated with p parameter.

Comment: I thought it would be clear from the code. I have added a section about this to my answer just now. The `p` parameter is just an array with a longitude and a latitude value.

Comment: great that fine, however, when I give x = -62.846468 and y = -22.034985 and x = -65.5, y = -55.2 then it does not return any country it returns null.

Comment: Those coordinates are out of the range of the sample data you have given, so it is normal there is no match. The range of the data you have given has a range of x between 11 and 76, and y between -18 and 43.

Comment: That is sample data. There is a lot more. The range of x is -90 to 90 and range of y is -180 to 180.

Comment: I understand, but unless you provide the data, I cannot verify the claim that the point you look for should match a country that is in your data set. Any way you can point me to the full set?

Comment: I'll certainly get back to you later. At work now :-)

Comment: As I see it there is no problem: I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znc1Lpot/2/. You can enter coordinates and zoom in on that position. The first pair you gave returns Bolivia. The second returns nothing. This is normal. A point on a polygon will be interpreted to belong to one side of it. In the latter case, that side happens to be the ocean.... It is determined by the order of the points in the polygon (clockwise or anti-clockwise). If you take (-65.5, -55.1999) you'll have Argentina as match.

Comment: Was this answer useful? Do you still have an issue with the points on the borders? Can you leave a comment?

Comment: Yes, it really helps me out. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Nice to know! Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `coordinates` is just another nested coordinate array in case of multiploygon but the structure is same so try something like this:

```
var list = feat;//feat has the json response
list.forEach(function(val, index)
{
  var temp = val.geometry;
  var set = [];
  var type = temp.type.toLowerCase();//just for sake of simplicity
  var coords = [];
  if(type=='polygon')
   coords = temp.coordinates[0];//which is an array of long-lats
  else
  {
    var a = [];
    temp.coordinates.forEach(function(coord)
    {
     a.concat(coord[0]);//note that the 0th index of each array has the list of long-lats
    })
   coords = a;
  }
  temp.coordinates = coords;
});
```

`coordinates` key of each object should now have a 1D array of list of lat-longs. I haven't tested this code so please do check it. You can test each index of `coordinates` for a given pair of lat-long. Please note that the above code just simplifies your response structure, and does not perform an actual search.

Comment: Sometimes it is polygon and sometimes the data is multipolygon.

Comment: The this how can I get the country? With current solution I get coordinates based on type. Then I have to loop through those coordinates to find users input long lat. Even with this process if I find user given long and lat then finding country would be hard.

Comment: The only thing changed here is the structure of `coordinates` so you still have access to other properties like you had earlier. You can get other properties of your object to find country name!